# Issues with DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, datatrigger

I am having issues getting a DataTrigger to call a Storyboard in WPF. I have been working on this for nearly 3 hours so hopefully someone can help!

Here is my XAML Snippet which contains the Storyboard/Trigger.

```
<Style x:Key="image" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="LoadTitleScreen">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoginWrong}" Value="true">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource LoadTitleScreen}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here is my C# code to set the value of the DataTrigger propery:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private Boolean _isLoginWrong;
    public Boolean IsLoginWrong
    {
        get { return this._isLoginWrong; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._isLoginWrong)
            {
                this._isLoginWrong = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoginWrong");
            }
        }
    }

    Timer ConnectToServer = new Timer(3000);


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectToServer.Elapsed += ConnectToServer_Elapsed;
        ConnectToServer.Start();
    }

    void ConnectToServer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsLoginWrong = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and call `NotifyPropertyChanged` in your `IsLoginWrong` setter.

Comment: I have updated the code but still no trigger in the XAML upon executing. I have breakpointed the program and IsLoginWrong has a value of true after the set. Any more ideas? Thanks! @kyriacos_k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsLoginWrong must be a dependency property or a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged so your Trigger can be notified that it has changed.

How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have implemented this interface but still no trigger. I have updated the code above to reflect the changes. Still isn't working, any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You had to put DataContext= this; in your MainWindow constructor and remove Storyboard.TargetName="image" from your code. I had tried and works fine with these little changes.

Comment: I finally have got it working! Thank you very much for your help in the matter. Have an upvote =D

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept answer if it helped you. Good work.